# jQuery plugin to get and set css3 transform style

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins, css-transforms

Like as title, there is some library to get and set css3 transform property?

For example i need something like this:

```
$("#elem").translate({x : 900, y : 300}).rotate(90).skewX(30)
```

Because as we know if we do:

```
 $("#elem").css("transform", "translate(900,300)");
 $("#elem").css("transform", "rotate(90deg)"); // This will replace the previous one
```

The transform rotate will replace the previous transform property.

I have found plugins like [jquery.transform.js](http://louisremi.github.io/jquery.transform.js/index.html) or [jquery.transit.js](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) but this plugins can add only cssHooks for using it with **.animate({})**

So i've missed someone? I should write one for my own?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a space-separated directive list to achieve the desired effect, just as with a stylesheet entry...

```
$('#elem').css("transform", "translate(900px,300px) rotate(90deg) skewX(30deg)");
```

Hope that helped. :)

Comment: Thanks but it's not what i'm looking for.. For example in a plugin context, i need to update transform values in different methods